# FacebookId as primary key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, facebook, database-design, facebook-graph-api

Will the facebookId ever change? If not, Is it safe to use it in my app as the primary key?

```
FACEBOOK_USER
FacebookId (PK)
Name

FACEBOOK_FRIEND
Id
OwnerFacebookId (FK)
FriendFacebookId (FK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook ID will not change, as facebook also treating them as primary key. But email ID can be changed so dont use email ID as primary key.
I already using the facebook ID as primary key.

Comment: Facebook users can change their Facebook ID by getting a different Facebook account. I know several people who have done that.

Comment: Conceptually though this just means this user is has multiple Facebook accounts.  A given Facebook account though has a static facebookid that does not change for the lifetime of the Facebook account.